# My script save results to DB with strange chars

Tags: php, database, character-encoding

I build a script which save into DB backlinks, anchor text,etc (I have to crawl about 100k urls) and when I send the information to DB it save like this:

```
ͧ�����ǡ�ȹҫ�
```

Sites where extract results like that are: chinese, russians, taiwan, etc. How can I fix that to save have a normal result in UTF-8?

Comment: You'll need to show us your script

Answer (score 0):

try this in  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: @JohnSmith what is "default_charset" in your php.ini

Comment: ;default_charset = "UTF-8"

Comment: I forgot to say my script is a crawler with run with multi curl if this count.

Comment: @JohnSmith what is MySQL connection collation?

Comment: I don't use mysql, it's Hypertable, and the columns rows don't have option to chose the charset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68809/discussion-between-john-smith-and-priyank).